In Matthew 5:22 why there is so much difference in terms of guiltiness between saying Ῥακά ("silly, empty") and saying Μωρέ ("fool") to one's brother?
When explaining the new standards of righteousness required by the New Covenant of the Kingdom of Heaven, Jesus talks about two different kinds of insults. He says that just insulting a brother with the Aramaic word for "stupid, empty-minded" (Ῥακά) makes one liable to be brought in front of the Synhedrion, whereas telling him "foolish" (Μωρέ) makes that person liable to be thrown to the fiery hell (ἔνοχος ἔσται εἰς τὴν γέενναν τοῦ πυρός). Why is there such a big difference in liability for two insults that are seemingly quite close to one another?

I have come to the same conclusions as Betho's, even without going through the Shem Tov translation of the Gospel of Matthew, simply by checking the usages of μωρός (and derivatives) in other New Testament passages:
Mat 5:13 Ὑμεῖς ἐστε τὸ ἅλας τῆς γῆς· ἐὰν δὲ τὸ ἅλας μωρανθῇ, ἐν τίνι ἁλισθήσεται; εἰς οὐδὲν ἰσχύει ἔτι εἰ μὴ βληθὲν ἔξω καταπατεῖσθαι ὑπὸ τῶν ἀνθρώπων.
“You are the salt of the earth; but if the salt loses its flavor, how shall it be seasoned? It is then good for nothing but to be thrown out and trampled underfoot by men.
Mat 7:26 καὶ πᾶς ὁ ἀκούων μου τοὺς λόγους τούτους, καὶ μὴ ποιῶν αὐτοὺς, ὁμοιωθήσεται ἀνδρὶ μωρῷ, ὅστις ᾠκοδόμησεν αὐτοῦ τὴν οἰκίαν ἐπὶ τὴν ἄμμον.
But everyone who hears these sayings of Mine, and does not do them, will be like a foolish man who built his house on the sand
Mat 25:2 πέντε δὲ ἐξ αὐτῶν ἦσαν μωραὶ, καὶ πέντε φρόνιμοι.
Now five of them were wise, and five were foolish.
1Cor 1:25 Ὅτι τὸ μωρὸν τοῦ Θεοῦ σοφώτερον τῶν ἀνθρώπων ἐστίν, καὶ τὸ ἀσθενὲς τοῦ Θεοῦ ἰσχυρότερον τῶν ἀνθρώπων.
Because the foolishness of God is wiser than men, and the weakness of God is stronger than men.
1Cor 1:27 ἀλλὰ τὰ μωρὰ τοῦ κόσμου ἐξελέξατο ὁ Θεός ἵνα καταισχύνῃ τοὺς σοφούς· καὶ τὰ ἀσθενῆ τοῦ κόσμου ἐξελέξατο ὁ Θεός ἵνα καταισχύνῃ τὰ ἰσχυρά·
But God has chosen the foolish things of the world to put to shame the wise, and God has chosen the weak things of the world to put to shame the things which are mighty;
1Cor 3:18 Μηδεὶς ἑαυτὸν ἐξαπατάτω· εἴ τις δοκεῖ σοφὸς εἶναι ἐν ὑμῖν ἐν τῷ αἰῶνι τούτῳ, μωρὸς γενέσθω, ἵνα γένηται σοφός.
Let no one deceive himself. If anyone among you seems to be wise in this age, let him become a fool that he may become wise.
I have also found the word used in some other important passages of the LXX Greek version of prophetic books in the Old Testament, namely
Jer 5:21 ἀκούσατε δὴ ταῦτα, λαὸς μωρὸς (סָכָ֖ל) καὶ ἀκάρδιος· ὀφθαλμοὶ αὐτοῖς καὶ οὐ βλέπουσιν, ὦτα αὐτοῖς καὶ οὐκ ἀκούουσιν.
21 ‘Hear this now, O foolish people,
Without understanding,
Who have eyes and see not,
And who have ears and hear not:
Isa 32:6 ὁ γὰρ μωρὸς μωρὰ (נָבָל֙ נְבָלָ֣ה) λαλήσει, καὶ ἡ καρδία αὐτοῦ μάταια νοήσει, τοῦ συντελεῖν ἄνομα καὶ λαλεῖν πρὸς Κύριον πλάνησιν, τοῦ διασπεῖραι ψυχὰς πεινώσας, καὶ τὰς ψυχὰς τὰς διψώσας κενὰς ποιήσει.
For the foolish person will speak foolishness,
And his heart will work iniquity:
To practice ungodliness,
To utter error against the LORD,
To keep the hungry unsatisfied,
And he will cause the drink of the thirsty to fail.
All these paassages strongly suggest that the third of the insults mentioned in Matthew 5:22 is liable to such an ultimate condemnation because it is indeed much heavier than the previous two. In fact, it involves not just the insulted person's quality but also, most importantly, his system of values, namely his faith in God. Along this line of thought, we can think of Isa 5:20 ("Woe to those who call evil good, and good evil; Who put darkness for light, and light for darkness; Who put bitter for sweet, and sweet for bitter!"). And also remember the heaviness of the Lord Jesus' reply to Peter in Mat 16:23 (“Get behind Me, Satan! You are an offense to Me, for you are not mindful of the things of God, but the things of men.")
One who insults a brother, i.e., a believer in God as a "fool," does so because he takes as valid his own natural value system (the "old-man" disobedient knowledge of good and evil) and therefore considers God's system of values as foolishness. That is, he consciously takes sides for the world, which entirely lies under the power of the evil one (1 John 5:19) and, therefore, under eternal condemnation. On the other hand, what kind of "brother" could this person be, if not a hypocrite? I think this understanding is very much in line with the whole Sermon, where the Lord strongly introduces to his disciples the true godly system of values a believer must hold to.

This part of Mt. 5 establishes a pattern in which Jesus cites the Law of Moses and urges his disciples to go beyond that standard so that their righteousness may exceed even that of the Pharisees. His intent is not to establish a new legalistic standard, but to go beyond the letter of the law.  Here, Jesus emphasizes that it is not enough to refrain from killing in anger, but one must overcome anger itself.

21 “You have heard that it was said to your ancestors, ‘You shall not
kill; and whoever kills will be liable to judgment.’ 22 But I say to
you, whoever is angry with his brother will be liable to judgment....

Ῥακά and Μωρέ are both insults. The problem in both cases is that anger has led to sin. But Jesus is not legislating here; he is admonishing.
Jesus used a similar formula in addressing the sin of lust: it is not enough to refrain from adultery. One must overcome the tendency to lust itself. Jesus follows this admonition by directing:

29 If your right eye causes you to sin, tear it out and throw it
away...30 And if your right hand causes you to sin, cut it off and
throw it away.

Just as Jesus did not literally command us to tear out our right eye if we look with lust at someone, he also did not intend his proposed legal punishment for anger to be taken literally. Being charged before the Sanhedrin (the supreme court of Judaism) and being liable to Gehenna are both hyperboles -- exaggerations made to emphasize that anger is a serious sin, especially if it results in verbal abuse. The intent is to teach us that anger must be controlled, not to enact legal punishments for using this word or that.

+1. Very good answer.

I agree with you that Jesus did not intend here to complicate the framework of legal casuistry but first and foremost to emphasize the importance of the inner life (also because the Father is the one who looks in the secret - ὁ βλέπων ἐν τῷ κρυπτῷ -  and not only at the appearance like does man), but I also think that this does not mean that here the Lord is exaggerating with the threat of hell. But this becomes another big issue.

In Matthew 5:22, the Greek words Ῥακά (rhaká) and Μωρέ (mōré) bring subtle but significant distinctions when compared with Shem Tov's Hebrew translation, which uses terms with specific nuances: וַאֲנִי אוֹמֵר לָכֶם שֶׁהַמַּכְעִיס לְחַבִירוֹ ("he who angers his friend"), וַאֲשֶׁר יִקְרָא לְאָחִיו פָּחוֹת ("he who calls his brother insignificant"), and וַאֲשֶׁר יִקְרְאוּהוּ שׁוֹטֶה ("he who calls him a fool").
The Greek word Ῥακά is an Aramaic transliteration meaning "empty" or "senseless," carrying the idea of someone without worth or intellect. In Shem Tov’s Hebrew, it is translated as פָּחוֹת (pachot), which literally means "less," "insignificant," or "of lower value." This term carries a connotation that devalues the other, treating them as inferior, an insult that could affect a person's social status and self-worth.
The term Μωρέ (mōré), translated as שׁוֹטֶה (shoté) in Hebrew, means "fool" in a more spiritual and moral sense, implying a lack of discernment or moral perversion. The Hebrew term שׁוֹטֶה suggests more than intellectual foolishness; it is often used in rabbinic literature to characterize someone who acts against wisdom and the path of righteousness. Calling someone שׁוֹטֶה is graver, as it denotes not only a lack of judgment but also a rebellion against moral precepts.
In the context of Matthew 5:22, this escalation of responsibility and guilt reflects a progression in the degree of offense:

He who “angers” his friend - The Hebrew uses חַיָּיב לְמִשְׁפָּט (chayyav le-mishpat), implying guilt before a court, though not yet before God or in eternal condemnation. This first level represents the sin of inconsideration, a type of "social fault."

He who calls his brother "insignificant" (Ῥακά / פָּחוֹת) - This insult is more serious, as it diminishes the other’s image. According to Shem Tov, the offender would be "guilty before the council" (בְּמִשְׁפָּט בְּהַקָּהָל). In a Jewish context, judgment by the council or Sanhedrin was a public matter of greater severity.

He who calls his brother a "fool" (Μωρέ / שׁוֹטֶה) - Here, the gravity reaches its peak, leading to condemnation in the "fire of Gehinnom." This insult directly challenges the moral character and spiritual value of the person, as if condemning them. The use of שׁוֹטֶה implies a violation of the other's dignity to the extent that the offender becomes accountable before God.


Thus, the progression of guilt in Matthew 5:22—from irritation to moral insult—is not merely about the intensity of the insult but about a scale of judgment on the spiritual condition and dignity of the other person. This condemnation culminates in an offense against the very concept of the divine image in one's neighbor, thereby drawing severe spiritual judgment.

Direct answer to the question and well researched.

I don't think the three clauses are intended to be contrastive, but complementary.
I don't think a semantic difference is intended between being angry or insulting or contemptuous of one's brother. Or in the penalties.
The effect is cumulative.

I don't think the clauses are intended to be contrastive either. However I maintain that there is a big difference between the last two. My question was about the leap in gravity of the guiltiness between the second and the third case of expression of anger. I think that the difference points out a different kind of arrogance. One is  horizontally addressed at the insulted person. The other one is devilishly and vertically addressed at God.
